# Mongodb only gets ID: posted, not the data from the form

Tags: javascript, node.js, json, mongodb

I want to send data to my MongoDB with a form via a POST method.

It seems as if everything works correctly.
A POST is being made to the mongoDB when I click the submit button, as expected, however the POST does not contain the data I entered into the form. The only thing posted to the DB is an ID.

```
id  "5db45de0658c801a8813fa7f"
__v 0
```

Here the code snippet from my controller for the POST method:

```
let bodyParser = require('body-parser');
let mongoose = require('mongoose');

mongoose.connect('?????????', {useUnifiedTopology: true, useNewUrlParser: true, useCreateIndex: true });

let Schema = mongoose.Schema;

//the proposed schema
let TaskSchema_Kid = new Schema({
  task: String
});

// creates the document "database in MongoDB"
let Task = mongoose.model('Task', TaskSchema_Kid);

let urlencodedParser = bodyParser.urlencoded({extended: false});

module.exports = function (app) {
  app.post('/todoParents' , urlencodedParser, function (req, res) {
    let newTask = Task(req.body).save(function (err, data) {
      if (err) throw err;
      res.json(data);
      console.log('something happened')
    })
  })

}
```

Here the code from the task.js:

```
  let submitButton = document.getElementById('button');
  let textField = document.getElementById('input');

  submitButton.addEventListener('click' , addItem);

  function addItem() {

    let newTask = textField.value;
    let task = {
      item: newTask
    }
    console.log(task)

    fetch("/todoParents", {
      method: 'POST',
      headers: {
        'Content-Type': 'application/json'
      },
      body: JSON.stringify(task)
    }).then((res) => res.json())
    .then((data) => console.log(data))
    .catch((err) => console.log(err))

  }

};
```

Here is the todoParents.ejs

```
<body>

    <div class="wrapper">

        <div class="assign">
          <form action="" method="post">
              <input id="input" name="input" type="text" placeholder="assign Task">
              <button id="button" type="submit">Burden the children</button>
            </form>
        </div>

        <div class="container">
          <h1>Time to burden the children</h1>

          <ul>
              <% for(var i=0; i < todos.length; i++) { %>
                <li><%= todos[i].item %> </li>
             <% } %>
          </ul>


        </div>
      </div>

      <script src="../public/assets/tasks.js"></script>

</body>
```

Answer (score 1):

While sending data task is an object with field item

```
let task = {
  item: newTask
}
```

but your schema wants task as a string.

One more issue can be you are stringifying body and Task(Object).save() requires object.

Comment: Changed the the item to task but does not work. Regarding stringify, what should I do instead?

Comment: just pass the object in the body instead of a string

Comment: or at api end do JSON.parse() do console.log() aswell to check if the data is there or not

Answer (score 0):

Based on your schema, an object with the key 'task' is expected.

```js
let TaskSchema_Kid = new Schema({
  task: String
});
```

However, in task.js, you have defined the object with the key 'item'

```js
 let task = {
   item: newTask
 }
```

Therefore `req.body`  has an object with the following structure

```js
{
 item:foo
}
```

## Solution

In `task.js` change `item` to `task`

```js
 let task = {
   task: newTask
 }
```

Comment: I fear this is not the solution, yet.